# Hiding usernames in slither.io

Tags: slither.io

Is there a way that you can hide other people's usernames in the game slither.io? Perhaps a mod or a setting that can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a setting that allows you to hide other people's names in slither.io. Though you could find a mod, I don't think there is actually a way to do it.